# Mapreduce multiple map and reducer

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I had csv files the data are as follows

```
lat,lng
18.1234,77.3443
18.345,77.335
18.356,77.345
```

so basically contains Latitude and longitude and each CSV file is upto 1mb,I needed to calculate distance from Latitude and Longitude from first record and second record of CSV.

```
i.e 18.1234, 77.3443 and 18.345, 77.335.
```

But from mapper it will read one line at a time so i am thinking to add delimeter('|') between lines,So above CSV file records will become as one line and Input for Mapper

```
Key->Filename
values-> All csv records as one line (all records seprated by delimetr) as text.

filename  18.1234,77.3443|18.345,77.335|18.356,77.345....
```

In Reducer i will split by delimeter and calculate distance between subsequent records[first and second coordinates].

So if i have 30 CSV files i want to 30 mappers and 30 reducers to process this CSV files.
Also i need to store this data in MySql. such as lat,lng,distance

Comment: If there is a 1-to-1 mapping between the mapper and the reducer, I don't see the reason for having a reducer. You can better have a map only job, it's much more efficient since there is no shuffling of the data between the mappers and the reducers.

Comment: The data from csv file is related to each other[previous record is related to next record],so i am thinking make  mapreduce  like OneFile->Map1->Readucer1.... and so on.Is it correct what i am doing

Comment: I think @PraveenSripati is right. Can you describe the problem that you are trying to solve? Maybe it can be solved in another way than the one you think.

Comment: Thanks for reply,Also i described my problem statement in main Thread.

Answer (score 0):

If each csv file is smaller than the default block size, simply get the id of the current mapper and emit it as a key.

I believe you can get this id with `conf.get("mapred.tip.id")` from the mapper's configuration.

Comment: Thank you.. Just want to know if csv file is greater than block size then is it possible.

Comment: One simple solution is to increase default block size, setting it greater than your biggest csv file. Otherwise, you can get the fileName of your input file and set your map output key accordingly.